# Query in sql server 2012 with datetime between takes too long with millisecond difference

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, date-comparison

I have a strange issue with a database and a query in sql server 2012.

in the records, are one column that is of type **datetime** (not datetime2) and stores the values in the format `'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt'` but i have a problem... if i make this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 cg 
INNER JOIN table2 mv ON cg.mv_id = mv.mv_id 
FULL JOIN table3 fu ON cg.fu_id = fu.fu_id 
FULL JOIN table4 cl ON cg.cl_id = cl.cl_id 
INNER JOIN table5 so ON mv.so_id = so.so_id 
WHERE  mv.su_id = 1 AND (mv.mv_fecha >= '2013-09-02 17:46:03.571' AND mv.mv_fecha <= '2013-09-04 23:59:59.999')
```

Then takes like 10 seconds, but if i change the `mv.mv_fecha >= '2013-09-02 17:46:03.571'` to `'2013-09-02 17:46:03.572'` (note that i change millisecond 571 to 572) then the query takes like 4 minutes! and i'ts only with this record.. and if i make any query passing that millisecond, the query takes that loooong time.
I must specify that casually there is a record in the **table2** with a **mv_fecha** like `'2013-09-02 17:46:03.573'` but even if there is a record with that datetime, the query wont retrieve it because it's a record with **su_id = 2** (and in the query the **su_id** filtered is 1).

What's going on???

UPDATE: I have some theory with **table1**.. and it's that **table1** have thousands of records and it's a table that doesn't contain any index in it?... could be that the problem?

UPDATE 2: This is the execution plan of the query:

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Probably statistics need updating. What are the estimated number of rows matching `mv_fecha >= '2013-09-02 17:46:03.570'` and what are the estimated matching `mv_fecha >= '2013-09-02 17:46:03.573'`?

Comment: Also the use of `FULL JOIN` is pointless. Your `WHERE` clause converts it back to inner joins.

Comment: Can you tell me where do i find this numbers?

Comment: Run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable mv WHERE  mv.su_id = 1 AND (mv.mv_fecha >= '2013-09-02 17:46:03.571' AND mv.mv_fecha <= '2013-09-04 23:59:59.999')` in SSMS with the "actual execution plan" option enabled and mouse over the arrows in the plan to see the estimated and actual rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query -

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 cg
JOIN table2 mv ON cg.mv_id = mv.mv_id
FULL JOIN table3 fu ON cg.fu_id = fu.fu_id
FULL JOIN table4 cl ON cg.cl_id = cl.cl_id
JOIN table5 so ON mv.so_id = so.so_id
WHERE mv.su_id = 1
    AND CAST(mv.mv_fecha AS DATETIME2) BETWEEN '20130902 17:46:03.572' AND '20130904 23:59:59.999')
```

Comment: With that query now takes too long from 574 millisecond :/

Comment: Please provide execution plan for this query, `DDL` for your tables and small dataset for testing.